# Remote Desktop Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, rdc

If I am asking on the wrong stack exchange site, please let me know. We have a remote server that we connect to using Remote Desktop Connection. It works when we enter the IP address 192.x.x.x . The Cisco router we use has only 4 ethernet ports and to try and add more, we connected a Netgear router to it but the computers we have connected to it will connect to the internet but won't connect to the Remote Desktop.

The chain is Modem

I appreciate the help

Comment: Did you disable the DHCP server on the Netgear router and only plug in the LAN ports to daisy-chain with?  Why not just buy a small switch for $20 and use that instead?

Comment: Originally we bought this one to enable wireless in our store but didn't realize that the laptops we were to bring in wouldn't have working wireless cards. So now I am trying to use what I have and get the Netgear router to daisy chain.

Comment: Simply disable the dhcp server on the Netgear, set the LAN interface IP on it to something static that isn't in use on your LAN, plug one of its LAN ports into the upstream router/switch ports and then use the other LAN ports on it for clients.  Tape a piece of tape over the WAN port on it, and just don't use that one.

Answer (score 3):

It's likely behind a double-NAT boundary created by two SOHO routers. You should either remove one NAT layer, or configure forwarding through both for TCP/3389 to the server that you want to RDP into.

Comment: Would I remove a NAT layer by (example) going into the Netgear Settings?

Comment: The easiest way would be to use a switch and not a second router to extend your network. Or you can try reading the netgear manual...